# Timeout exception after couple of nack exception in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I using rabbitmq and i want to limit my queues to 100,000 messagegs so i add policy like this : `rabbitmqctl set_policy my-pol "^two-messages$" '{"max-length":2,"overflow":"reject-publish"}' --apply-to queues`

This working fine and limit my queue.

Now when I got a nack exception I want the thread to sleep incremental time, i did it like this:

```
public static async Task SendMessagage(Uri queueUri, T message, IBus bus, int interval = 10 * 1000)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<ISendEndpoint> sendEndpointTask = bus.GetSendEndpoint(queueUri);
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter SendMessagage {queueUri.AbsolutePath}  interval={interval}");
            var result  = sendEndpointTask.Result;
            await result.Send(message);
            Console.WriteLine($"AFTER SEND SendMessagage {queueUri.AbsolutePath}  interval={interval}");
            interval = 10 * 1000;
        }
        catch (PublishNackException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"PublishNack EXCEPTION SendMessagage {queueUri.AbsolutePath}  interval={interval}");
            interval = interval * 2;
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
            await SendMessagage(queueUri, message, bus);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"EXCEPTION SendMessagage {queueUri.AbsolutePath}  interval={interval}");
            interval = interval * 2;
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
            await SendMessagage(queueUri, message, bus);
            Console.WriteLine($"EXCEPTION2 SendMessagage {queueUri.AbsolutePath}  interval={interval}");
        }
    }
```

but after time i got timeout exception.
Why I am getting this exception and there is a time that a consumer needs to give a response?

The exception is:

```
 The model usage threw an exception
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
 at RabbitMQ.Util.BlockingCell.GetValue(TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model._Private_ChannelOpen(String outOfBand)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.CreateModel()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqModelCache.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<SendUsingNewModel>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqModelCache.ModelScope.<Attach>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqModelCache.<SendUsingExistingModel>d__10.MoveNext()
```

I saw in the log file that after NackException that i caught rabbitmq is closing dont know why, the message in the log is:

```
13/5/2018 16:14:42.594 [Debug] (8) Closing model: 5 / "admin@192.168.153.103:5672/"
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact exception and stack trace?

Comment: Added the exception

Comment: The last line indicates channel closure. That would happen anytime you trigger a protocol exception - for example, trying to publish to a full queue (as defined by your code, any time queue length > 2, an attempt to publish is an exception and will close the channel). Not sure if that's the exact reason, as it is impossible to determine on the limited information provided.

Comment: So, my best guess is that the reason you're getting a timeout is that the reply is never sent, but that is just a guess. You're going to have to do more debugging on your end to figure out exactly what is happening.

Comment: I would try to do this operation without using `MassTransit` and without using recursion.